# Bit pattern in a sequence

Tags: bit, string-matching, pattern-recognition

I am trying to identify any existing bit patterns, which exists in a 32 bit sequence. The bit pattern length varies, and can be anywhere between 2 to 32.
For example, how many different bit pattern exists in following data (`11,101,110,1100,1010,11001010,etc`) and how many times each pattern is repeated.

Looks like a difficult problem..any guidance will be helpful.

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0 
1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1
```

Is there an easier way to write dynamic code to do this?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward brute force approach would be like this :

1. Start from the very first bit position.
2. Check if the current bit position exceeds bit length of the bit string, if it exceeds length of bit string go to step 6.
3. Check if the total bit string can be formed by the repeatation of current pattern. Current pattern is formed from the first bit to current bit position.
4. If it is possible to form the bit string by the current pattern put this pattern in solution set.
5. Increase bit position by one and go to step 2.
6. End

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am not sure if this will work, as the task is to identify and count the bit patterns of variable length. Length can vary from 2 to 32 bits.For example - if there are three bit patterns: 101,110 - so we need to check 2^2+2^3 bit patterns such as 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111; 00,01,10,11 - and see how many times each repeated. So, the problem with brute force is it will get too long.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task. I don't know how to solve it in an optimal and efficient way, but you can try the following approach:

- Step 1: [Generate n-bit Gray Codes](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-number-n-generate-bit-patterns-from-0-to-2n-1-so-that-successive-patterns-differ-by-one-bit/) and store it somewhere
- Step 2: Search for every code from generated list in a given sequence with one of the search algorithms:

  - brute-force
  - Knuth-Morris-Pratt
  - Boyer-Moore's
  - Rabin-Karp
  - other

As I've written above, it may be inefficient and may take a long time to execute (especially if you are going to identify every bit sequence up to 32), so you can try to search for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response, only issue with brute force is that there will be lot of permutations and combination. 2^32 +2^31+2^30+2^....+2^2 permutations.

Comment: I know it's not efficient as I wrote earlier. I think, searching for an efficient solution would require more time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest brute-force approach is to slide a 2-bit window over the data, counting the 2-bit codes you find.
Then, slide a 3-bit window, then... finally a 32-bit window.

It isn't elegant, but all you need is a hash map of counters (per bit length) and potentially lots of memory, and you have a linear-time solution.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, so at the end of the stream check, when I would like to know how many such patterns occurred, how can I incorporate this?

Comment: You'll have some collection of maps, just sum their lengths to find out how many distinct patterns were found. Try writing some code and ask if you have a concrete problem with it